# problems of visualization in classes

Tags: ubuntu, visualization, eclipse-mars

Hi to everyone: I've a strange problem in the code visualization.. Instead of explain what's happening to me, I'll show you: 
[picture_problem:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfwWl.png)

It's a very annoying situation: Eclipse doesn't give any errors and the code compiles correctly.. What should I do to try to resolve this issue?
Advance thanks for all of your answers! 
P.s. (I have Ubuntu 16.10 and I use open-jdk [but the problem was the same with jdk by Java]).

Comment: Are you using some non Latin alphabet? what is the original supposed to be?

Comment: mmmh.. I don't know if my answer is appropriate with your question, but some days ago I decided to clean up my pc, deleting some language packages that I didn't think I would serve (like japanese or korean).. Do you think the problem is that?.. But now I didn' remember what I deleted..

Comment: [Samer] p.s. The problem disappears if I comment the three lines.. so it's not a character visualization (or encoding) problem..